# Create "bracket free" macros (like in mimeTeX)

Tags: math-mode, macros, brackets

In [mimeTeX](http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.html), an abundance of macros like `\cd` = `\cdot`, `\fr` = `\frac` and `\sq` = `\sqrt` are allowed. This kind of macros are easily created in own LaTeX documentens, using `\newcommand`. Other mimeTeX macros are so to speak "bracket free"; for instance, `\te hallo` is possible to use instead of `\text{hello}`. My question is, whether this kind of macros too are possible to imitate in LaTeX, and, if so, how that is done.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\def` to make macros with delimited arguments so

```
\def\te#1 {\text{#1}}
 \te hello aaa
```

would put `hello` in the argument to `\text`. The argument to `te` ends at the first space (or newline) where the space after `\te` does not count as it never makes a space token, it is used to terminate the command name.

However in general you should not do this. A major design aim in LaTeX is to give a consistent top level syntax to commands: mandatory arguments get `{}` optional arguments get `[]` etc.

---

Judging from the use case in the comments it seems that you do not in fact want want `\te` to take an argument at all but want the plain Tex/LaTeX2.09 usage

```
\newcommand\te{\rm}
```

will make `\te` switch to an upright roman font for the rest of the current expression.

Comment: Great! Is it possible to make it work for longer arguments, like `\te how do you do` (that should be interpreted as `\text{how do you do}`? The reason I'm asking this is that I'm converting from mimeTeX to mathJax on a web forum where `\te` is frequently used in the beginning of math environments to generate chemical reaction formulas and similar non-italic objects.

Comment: Yes but you need to replace the ` `  that I put in the definition before `{` by whatever sequence of tokens you want to end the argument, you need some marker eg `\par` will work to go as far as the next blank line. But beware this is a TeX forum and this is a TeX answer, MathJax does not use TeX, it emulates simple TeX syntax but if you do anything too tricky  with low level tex code it will not be supported.

Comment: @PoetryInMotion, yes, you can do this. But latex need to know where is the end of macro's argument. So, you can write `\def\te#1|{\text{#1}}` and after this write `\te More than one word|`. All text till `|` will become argument of `\text`.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is the already existing forum posts, where I cannot easily add anything.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to existing mimetex content. How would LaTeX react if I let the end markers be omitted in old posts?

Comment: @PoetryInMotion the [mimetex manual](http://www.forkosh.com/mimetexmanual.html) doesn't mention `\te` syntax at all as far as I can see, what does terminate the argument in your case?

Comment: Currently, the forum users include mathematical content in posts by writing [tex]`1+\fr{1}{2}`[/tex], [tex]`\te H_2O \rightarrow H_2 + \fr{1}{2}O_2`[/tex] or similar. The content within the [tex] tags is typeset with mimetex. In the future, however, I wish to be able to use mathjax instead, which from default doesn't support  `\fr` or `\te`.

Comment: yes but what I mean is what in mimetex ends the argument to `\te` the command (or any other command with that kind of syntax) is not mentioned at all in the manual at the link I gave above. If you said said how the argument to `\te` works in mimetex we can show you how to define that in tex and mathjax.

Comment: Unfortunately I know very little about how mimetex actually works and I have noticed before that this kind of macros aren't mentioned in the manual. Will try to investigate this further.

Comment: An example of a mimetex editor: http://tools.vidirat.net/.
[tex]`\te a b c x^2`[/tex] would today generate the same as [tex]`\text{a b c x^2}`[/tex].

Comment: @PoetryInMotion But that's a syntax error in Tex and just generates an error message as you can't have math mode `^` inside the nested text region, Why would you want that?

Comment: answer updated. that online tool confirmed thet \te works like \rm in mimetex (although not like \rm in tex, but perhaps near enough)

Comment: Yes, that's another strange feature of mimetex I will have to handle...